# Help with simple prolog exercise

Tags: prolog

I haven't been able to solve this prolog exercise. I was hoping someone here could give me some hints or post a solution. Thanks in advance.

Database:

```
lig(super, porto).  
lig(super, benfica).  
lig(super, sporting).  
lig(honra, feirense).  
lig(honra, guimaraes).  

jog(sporting, ricardo, gr).  
jog(guimaraes, cleber, de).  
jog(feirense, edgar, me).  
jog(porto, quaresma, av).  
jog(porto, helton, gr).  
jog(benfica, simao, av).  
jog(sporting, moutinho, me).
```

The sample output:

```
?- calcula(Lista).
Lista = [super-[porto-[quaresma,helton], benfica-[simao], sporting-
[moutinho,ricardo]], honra-[ feirense-[edgar], guimarães-[cleber]]].
```

My procedure:

```
calcula(Lista) :-
    findall(Lig-[Eq-[X]],
            (lig(Lig, Eq), findall(Jog, jog(Eq, Jog, _), X)),
            Lista).
```

My output (which is wrong!).

```
Lista = [super-[porto-[[quaresma, helton]]], super-[benfica-[[simao]]], super-[sporting-[[ricardo, moutinho]]], honra-[feirense-[[edgar]]]
```

Comment: It seems the only thing wrong about the output is the extra pair of square brackets around each list of names.  Examining your code, can you see what might account for that extra pair of brackets and how to fix the problem?  It's worth a try.

Comment: that's not the only thing wrong. I am repeating the 'super' in the output, and I shouldn't. It should appear only once. I have no idea how to fix that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in the zfm's solution, the predicate `lig(Lig, _)` becomes true 5 times so there is some duplication in the final list. You can use the predicate `setof/3` and existential quantified variable `Eq0^` to remove duplication:

```
calcula(T) :- setof(Lig-X, Eq0^(lig(Lig, Eq0), 
              findall(Eq-U, (lig(Lig,Eq), findall(Jog, jog(Eq, Jog, _), U)), X)), T).
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm so interested to the question, I try it a lot.

Well, this is, I believe, not the best answer. However I get the result.

```
calcula(Ans):-findall(Lig-X, (lig(Lig, _), 
    findall(Eq-U, (lig(Lig,Eq), findall(Jog, jog(Eq, Jog, _), U)), X)), T), 
    removeEq(T,Ans).

removeEq([A-B,A-_|Tail], [A-B|TailChanged]) :- !, removeEq([A-B|Tail], 
    [A-B|TailChanged]).
removeEq([A-B,C-D|Tail], [A-B,C-D|TailChanged]) :- removeEq([A-B|Tail], 
    [A-B|TailTemp]), removeEq([C-D|TailTemp], [C-D|TailChanged]).
removeEq([X], [X]).
```

The `removeEq` is needed because there are duplicated answer (I don't know how not to duplicate it)

Comment: thanks for your solution. it does work. however, I am confident there is a simpler solution, only involving findalls I suppose. Thanks anyway.

Comment: me too, but I was just too tired to try more... I'll update the solution if I find one better.

Answer (score 1):

This is not shorter than zfm's answer, but it is "simpler" in the way that it only uses basic prolog constructs to construct the list directly. (No removal of duplicates afterward.) There is some code duplication which probably could be gotten rid of to get a shorter answer.

```
g(Second, [Third|Rest], Done) :- jog(Second, Third,_),
    not(member(Third, Done)),!,
    g(Second, Rest, [Third|Done]).
g(_,[],_).

f(First, [Second-New|Rest], Done) :- lig(First, Second),
    not(member(Second, Done)),!,
    g(Second, New, []),
    f(First, Rest, [Second|Done]).
f(_,[],_).  

h([First-X|Lista], Done):-
    lig(First,_),
    not(member(First, Done)),!,
    f(First, X, []),
    h(Lista,[First|Done]).
h([], _).

calcula(X) :- h(X, []).
```